# Why is windows 11 sending conventional DNS requests after enabling DNS-over-Https?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, doh, dns-over-https

I enabled DOH on my Wi-Fi. It works. But using Wireshark, I still see explicit DNS requests and see the DNS server refusing the requests.

Why is this happening, and what's the meaning of DOH to protect privacy if Windows keeps sending conventional DNS requests to be seen?

Comment: Have you set your DNS servers to one of the supported Cloudflare, Google and Quad9? ([link](https://www.howtogeek.com/765940/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-on-windows-11/))

Comment: @harrymc yes. The DNS works.

Comment: Which DNS are you using ?

Comment: @harrymc adguard and mullvad